# Which way is the best for lazy load angular material modules?

Tags: angular, angular-material, lazy-loading

1- Is it correct way to import all module of angular material module in a module like angular-material.module.ts then import that module in shared module?

2- If used the way above, when for example a component using  mat-input, only mat-input module is loaded or all modules that imported in angular-material.module.ts is loaded?

Answer (score 2):

For My Knowledge loading Angular Material Module into a single ts file , will not have effect on performance , the tree shaking helps to not load unused modules , so you are just giving paths, **Using a single Module it always helps in code refractioning.**

Answer (score 1):

If you want create shared components (and import them into different modules), you should create a single angular-material.module.ts and import into all lazy-loaded components that require them.

Otherwise you can just import the specific material modules you need into the lazy module

Answer (score 1):

Respecting Angular coding style, first solution is better. Create **material.module.ts** and import it into **shared.module.ts**

The difference between this solution and second (import only used modules) probably is too small in performance and will be more harder to be maintained.

Anyway, in your material.module.ts you can import only used libraries in your application and not entire material package. If you use lazy loading module, all modules used in your lazy module will load entire contain, so ... will load entire material imports.